# How to peek into source code of a built-in Powershell function?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, windows-10

Specifically interested in source code and workings of `Set-NetConnectionProfile` or `Get-NetConnectionProfile`, to understand how Windows resets network profiles ("Public" and "Private" in Network and Sharing Center).

I tried `(Get-Command Set-NetConnectionProfile).DLL` to find out which DLL supplies the code behind the command, but the string is null or empty. I was going to load the DLL in [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net) and take it from there.

Apparently, the two commands are functions, not cmdlets. Perhaps that's why there is no associated DLL?

Is there any way to find the intermediate representation or anything of the kind related to the two commands and hopefully disassemble it into something readable?

I am ultimately interested in how Windows gets and sets the profile category for a network, as I am having troubles with Windows resetting it on its own for my internal NAT network backed by a Hyper-V virtual switch (which does *not* have any entry in the registry under `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/NetworkList/Profiles` as is the case with say WiFi networks).

I am on Windows 10 x86_64 Education Edition, version 10.0.14393 (build 14393).

Comment: `(Get-Command Set-NetConnectionProfile).Definition`

Comment: Thanks, I think I saw it when I did `Get-Command Set-NetConnectionProfile | Format-List` but I am not sure which part of the spit-out text I should look at. The `Process` block? The whole thing looks like some kind of wrapper around some logic that's buried somewhere else entirely. It's all parameter assignment and something about `Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization`. Surely this cannot be it?

Comment: [`Cmdletization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.cmdletization(v=vs.85).aspx) means that the cmdlet wraps native code.

Comment: I thought it was .NET assemblies? By native code you mean x86/x86_64?